# Javascript - Fetch POST is aborting - WinError 10053

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, fetch

- I need to post some information for my javascript project course. The
  function is aborting when it goes to the fetch.
- I am using Chrome to test the project. It was "sending" sometimes , but now it is not working at all.
- To run app in Chrome i had to use "chrome.exe  --user-data-dir="D:\CS50" --disable-web-security" , otherwise it won´t work.
- With the inspector I also can see that it is like the
  "submit" button is clicked twice, any tips on how to fix this?
  PLEASE.

Can someone help me please?

**Error**

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51270)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host
```

**javascript**

```
function send_email(recipients, subject, body){
   console.log("Inside SendMail");
   console.log( `${recipients}`,`${subject}`, `${body}`);

   fetch('/emails', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
       body: JSON.stringify({
             recipients: recipients,
             subject: subject,
             body: body,
             })
       })
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(result => {
           console.log('Success:', result);
              alert("Message Sent!");
              load_mailbox('sent');
       })
        .catch((error) => {
              console.error('Error:', error);
        });
}
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends "mail/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="compose-view">
       <h3>New Email</h3>
       <form id="compose-form">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <div class="form-group">
               From: <input disabled class="form-control" id="compose-sender" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
             Subject:<input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
           </div>
             Message:<textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
             <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send E-mail" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form>
    </div>


{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="{% static 'mail/inbox.js'  %}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

**Python**

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def compose(request):

    # Composing a new email must be via POST
    if request.method != "POST":
        return JsonResponse({"error": "POST request required."}, status=400)

    # Check recipient emails
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    emails = [email.strip() for email in data.get("recipients").split(",")]
    if emails == [""]:
        return JsonResponse({
            "error": "At least one recipient required."
        }, status=400)

    # Convert email addresses to users
    recipients = []
    for email in emails:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            recipients.append(user)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({
                "error": f"User with email {email} does not exist."
            }, status=400)

    # Get contents of email
    subject = data.get("subject", "")
    body = data.get("body", "")

    # Create one email for each recipient, plus sender
    users = set()
    users.add(request.user)
    users.update(recipients)
    for user in users:
        email = Email(
            user=user,
            sender=request.user,
            subject=subject,
            body=body,
            read=user == request.user
        )
        email.save()
        for recipient in recipients:
            email.recipients.add(recipient)
        email.save()

    return JsonResponse({"message": "Email sent successfully."}, status=201)
```

Comment: Pleasy give us the part of `python`-code for request handler.

Comment: I sent the Python code, the teacher gave us all the python codes for this project, the objective is use javascript and html . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem resides here:

> mail.models.User.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one User -- it returned 2!

It expects one resource, but gets two. I would look at the controller that calls this method.

### Update

In Django the get() method expects one resource, but in this case two were given. As per the Django documentation on query, if you expect more than one resource you have to use the filter() method.

Source: [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: Please, how can i check this?

Comment: the multipleobjectsreturned is solved, but the WinError 10053]

Answer (score -1):

I think you can add `{ return false; }` at the end of the code snippet.
This prevents the default submission of the form which involves either reloading the current page or redirecting to a new one.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You've posted this as an anwer, but it's actually more suited as a comment. However, you'll need just a little more reputation to be able to do that.